# The maximum of $|\sin z|$ and hyperbolic trig functions

Tags: complex-analysis

This is an example problem in a book, but I am having trouble filling in some of the gaps. The problem is to find the maximum of $|\sin z|$ on $[0,2\pi] \times [0,2\pi]$.

So I know that $\sin z$ is entire, so the maximum modulus principle says that the maximum will occur on the boundary of the region. Now the way that the book solves this is by stating that $|\sin z|^2 = \sinh^2 y + \sin^2 x$. I don't understand how they came to that conclusion. I know that

$$\sinh y = \frac{e^y - e^{-y}}{2} \quad \text{and} \quad \sin x = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}.$$
So I have tried just plugging these into the equation, but I get nowhere. Any tips?

Also, is this the only way to answer this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand how they came to that conclusion.

That's just the addition theorem for the sine together with $\cos (iz) = \cosh z$ and $\sin (iz) = i\sinh z$:

$$\sin (x+iy) = \sin x \cos (iy) + \cos x \sin (iy) = \sin x \cosh y + i \cos x \sinh y,$$

and if $x,y$ are real, we get

$$\lvert \sin (x+iy)\rvert^2 = \sin^2 x \cosh^2 y + \cos^2 x \sinh^2 y = \sin^2 x + \sinh^2 y.$$